# Can train travelled some distances without engine?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, momentum, rotational-kinematics

Train rolles on track without engine over 12 km

how is it  possible ?

During engine changing , momentum is reason for rolling the train 1-2km but 12 km how?

[description of the incident](https://m.timesofindia.com/india/ahmedabad-puri-express-rolls-without-engine-for-13-km-7-susupended/amp_articleshow/63668476.cms)

Comment: “Ahmedabad-Puri express rolls **down** without engine for 13 km”

Comment: yes ,how is it possible sir?

Comment: Gravity pulled it down. Try setting a ball on a tilted tabletop and see what happens.

Comment: Gravity acts if track is inclined but track is not inclined.

Comment: Suppose gravity pulled it down but 12 km?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what your misconception is. The distance has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stopped, unpowered train cars to start rolling, the track must have a downhill angle. Once rolling, trains have a great deal of inertia, and little rolling friction, so once rolling they can take some distance to slow to a halt on level ground. The track from Titlagarh station towards Kesinga has a downwards slope. And it was reported the train skids meant to keep it in place were improperly set.